# Google workspace marketplace - download counter

Tags: google-workspace

Hello we have created an app for google drive for our product but the download counter on the marketplace does not match our internal counter, i was wondering if there is any way to check this or alternatively how often dos this counter update

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, if you provide a Google Analytics ID when you configure the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK for your app listing, you can monitor how users interact with your [app listing from Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/use-analytics#get_information_about_your_app_listing).

Also, the [Google Marketplace API](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/use-analytics#connect_usage_info_with_your_licensing_or_billing_server) lets you determine what domain have installed/uninstalled your app. You can use the API's [LicenseNotification](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/reference/rest/v2/licenseNotification) collection method to collect the activity of your app.

Regarding how often the counter updates, there is no estimate of how long it takes but if you still notice that numbers doesn't match, you can forward your report to the dedicated 'Send Feedback' channel. From the Google Marketplace page click on the (?) icon > 'Send Feedback'. You can also attach a screenshot to show the install count.